# How to add Javascript validations to Rails simple_form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to validate some inputs on my Rails simple_form. HTML is good but not working with many InAppBrowsers.

```
<%= simple_form_for(:member, :url => registration_path(:member), html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, label: "Adresse e-mail", placeholder: "jeanne.dupont@gmail.com" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to use Javascript to do this but I don't know how to implement it without plugin.

Any ideas ?
Many thanks

Comment: bind to the submit event for the form validate and if failure then [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
    $("#your-form-id" ).submit(function( event ) {
      if( your_validation() )
        return;
      else event.preventDefault();
    });
```

hope this helps.